# ¿Cómo bajarle el peso a una imagen en un file con jquery?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Según sé es complicado tratar con files por "seguridad", está muy reestringido, pero sí se puede obtener info como el nombre, ext, tamaño, etc. Mi objetivo es que el usuario suba una imagen y a esta imagen reducirle el peso para cuando sea mandada al servidor. Sé de app's que lo hacen, pero no comparten api, ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto con jquery?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
        //Cómo le bajo el peso a la imagen subida?

    
    //$.ajax...
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="myAction" id="form" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
  
</form>
```

Comment: Hola User. Quizá haya librerias o apis que te puedan reducir el peso cambiando la resolución de la imagen. De igual manera, esta pregunta es muy amplia ya que no muestras lo que has intentado y las soluciones pueden ser muchas. Te sugiero que investigues más e intentes implementarlo. Si entonces tienes dudas, preguntar aqui. Un saludo

Comment: pero quieres bajarle la resolucion o cambiarle el encoding?

Comment: Quiero bajarle el peso, si eso implica cambiarle la resolución o el encoding pues que así sea.

Comment: Hola, lois6 he buscado como dice la descripción, pero solo he encontrado apps sin apis, por eso acudo aquí. Seguro alguien ya ha tenido que pasar por esta situación y tal vez desee ayudarme diciéndome cómo le hizo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta web: http://punypng.com ofrece una API que puedes insertar en tu página web para comprimir imágenes. Si prefieres programarlo tu, con jQuery es difícil, te recomiendo usar PHP.

Comment: Lo malo es que estoy trabajando sobre java y no sobre php :s Y ya había visto esa API y varias más, supongo que ninguna será gratis u_u Gracias igual, la pondré como válida mañana.

Comment: De java no entiendo mucho, lo siento, espero que encuentres la solución. Muchas gracias! :)